# how to use custom font in a website

Tags: html, css

I have downloaded a font called "steelfish" that contains these files

> steelfish outline
>
> steelfish rg it
>
> steelfish rg

and I have set these in my css file like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Stellfish Outline';
    src: url('fonts/steelfish outline.ttf') format('truetype'),
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Stellfish Regular';
    src: url('fonts/steelfish rg.ttf') format('truetype'),
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Stellfish Italic';
    src: url('fonts/steelfish rg it.ttf') format('truetype'),
}
```

but when I try to apply my custom font to any text then it doesn't take that font style.

```
<strong style="font-family:'Steelfish Italic' ">
</strong>
```

I need help in this issue. 
thanks

Comment: Please do not rely on content from external websites to make your question understandable. Instead include any relevant information in your question.

Comment: what kind of information do you need to answer my question ?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. All I am saying is that unless you put all the relevant information from the links into your actual question it is unlikely that you will get a good answer. Ask yourself what information someone might need to answer the question, and then make sure that information is in the question, and not only on an external site.

Comment: Is it Steelfish or Stellfish? Your code shows both. Is that the problem?

Comment: So is that a typo on SO or is that in your code?

Comment: @Rob sorry I didn't get your point.

Comment: If you spelled it wrong in your code then this isn't going to work. Do you have it the correct way in your code?

Comment: @Rob: now I have correct their spelling but nothing happens. and still the font style is not applying.

Comment: Where is the code that loads the font into the document?

Comment: @KevinBoucher: I didn't understand your point.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the spaces in the file names or replace them with dashes. Then update your css accordingly.  Also, inline style declarations are kind of frowned upon.  Pull them into your css stylesheet if you can. They'll work like you have them, but not "proper".

Comment: sorry. I didn't understand your point. can you elaborate that ?

Comment: Rename your files to not have spaces in them.  For example, on your web server, :

rename steelfish outline.ttf 
to steelfish-outline.ttf

Then update your css stylesheet and make the same replacement.

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Stellfish Outline';
    src: url('fonts/steelfish-outline.ttf') format('truetype'),
}

Comment: I have tried the method you mentioned but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Google Fonts. It's really simple:

Select a font from their website (https://www.google.com/fonts) and import the file in your `<head></head>` tag:

```
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Then apply that font in your CSS:

```
    .text { font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; }
```

Comment: Actually this font is the requirement. thats why I am using it. I have no choice to use google font.

Comment: Oh I see. If you could link me the font files, I could try to see what's going on. For all we know, the font files could be corrupted.

Comment: I downloaded these files from this link http://www.dafont.com/steelfish.font?text=SET+LIFE%3A